# How do I edit multiple layers at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

How do I edit multiple layers in Photoshop at once? Highlighting them all or selecting them selectively while holding shift does not work (for example, when applying Layer Options effects to layers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adjustment layers can be useful here for the edits found in `Image > Adjustments`. More on these can be found [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/key-concepts/adjustment-layer.html).

For layer styles, do what you want to one layer. Once done, right click on that layer and click `Copy Layer Style`. Select all the other layers you want to apply it to then right click on one of them, then click `Paste Layer Style`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Is it possible to do this in batch?

Comment: If you select all the layers you want to (using shitf + click or ctrl +  click) then right click on one of them and select 'Apply Layer Style', you'll be able to apply it to many at once. For adjustment layers, just place all in a group and apply the style to the adjustment layer above it.

Comment: @Scott Brown, Just to be sure, because Adobe has changed its link structure, do you mean the following help text for Adjustment Layers? https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/key-concepts/adjustment-layer.html

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn yeah, looks like that's the new help for that feature. Thanks, I'll update the post

Comment: Great! Being a very amateurish Photoshop user, I've definitely learned something useful today, and I'm getting more and more amazed at the possibilities offered by those obscure menu items which I have never fully understood before... :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn no problem at all, keep learning!

Answer (score 3):

One method is to convert the layers into smart objects first. 
 First, select the layers you want to edit in the layers pane `ctrl+click` then right click and choose `convert to smart object`.

*(It might be a good idea to duplicate the layers first)*

Once that is complete, right click the smart object and click `Edit contents`.

This is basically another PSD file within the layer, you must commit the changes before it will take any effect within the normal PSD though. :)

Comment: There are numerous advantages to this.  
1. You can resize the smart object, and layer styles within the smart object scale too.  
2. You can apply "smart effects" on it, that don't really mess about with the contents, rather the projection of the said PSD file.  
3. As mentioned, you can still edit the insides of the smart object as freely as you would have before converting it. Only downside being the separate editing and 'committing'.  
  
+1 for the only proper way around it ;-)

Comment: Yeah, smart objects are pure awesome! :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I typically duplicate the layers I want to edit together and then merge them. (Keeping a copy of the original layers). This is a nice quick way when you're editing photos.

However, if I'm keeping the layers separate, I would recommend using the Adjustment Layers as Scott suggested. Though, this will effect all layers underneath the Adjustment Layer - though you could use some creative masking to ignore other layers (as long as the don't overlap on top).

Answer (score -1):

Group the layers together and apply the style to the the group.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Can you please explaine more what you mean, for example with showing screenshots what yone have to do?  How does your answer differ to the acepted?